# Terraform tries to duplicate resources each time module is called more than once

Tags: terraform

I am trying to implement our AWS infrastructure in Terraform. Currently my working structure looks somehow like this:

```
modules
  └ vpc
      └ main.tf
      └ variables.tf
  └ iam
      └ main.tf
      └ variables.tf
main.tf
variables.tf
staging.tf
production.tf
```

This structure is working fine, but I would like to move staging and production into their own modules, so it would now look more like this:

```
modules
  └ vpc
      └ main.tf
      └ variables.tf
  └ iam
      └ main.tf
      └ variables.tf
env
  └ production
      └ main.tf
      └ variables.tf
  └ staging
      └ main.tf
      └ variables.tf
main.tf
variables.tf
```

If while using this structure I try to import the vpc module into the staging and production module, Terraform plan tells me it will create new vpc resources under namespace: "module.staging.module.vpc", I don't even need to use anything from iam module - just import it, and then terraform thinks it needs to create all these new resources. Is there a way to solve this?

Here is what I have in vpc/main.tf:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "pi-cloud" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "pi-cloud"
  }
}
```

And env/staging/main.tf:

```
module "vpc" {
   source = "../../modules/vpc"
 }
```

Now terraform plan gives me this output:

```
# module.staging.module.vpc.aws_vpc.pi-cloud will be created
  + resource "aws_vpc" "pi-cloud" {
      + arn                              = (known after apply)
      + assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = false
      + cidr_block                       = "10.0.0.0/16"
      + default_network_acl_id           = (known after apply)
      + default_route_table_id           = (known after apply)
      + default_security_group_id        = (known after apply)
      + dhcp_options_id                  = (known after apply)
      + enable_classiclink               = (known after apply)
      + enable_classiclink_dns_support   = (known after apply)
      + enable_dns_hostnames             = (known after apply)
      + enable_dns_support               = true
      + id                               = (known after apply)
      + instance_tenancy                 = "default"
      + ipv6_association_id              = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block                  = (known after apply)
      + main_route_table_id              = (known after apply)
      + owner_id                         = (known after apply)
      + tags                             = {
          + "Name" = "pi-cloud"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `env` modules should actually be one module with multiple workspaces. That will fix your problem and adhere to best practices.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard ! I think I have to read up on terraform workspaces. Does that mean I would only import vpc and iam module once, correct?

Comment: Yes, you would only have the one module declaring your `vpc` and `iam` modules. You can use `terraform workspace select <env>` to switch between your staging and production. Each will have a unique state, and you can leverage the intrinsic `terraform.workspace` for any differences between the environments.

Comment: I just tried creating new terraform workspace and switched to it, but now terraform plan says it needs to create every single resource again.